# Problem with Polynomials

Tags: matlab

I write this code in MATLAB :

> > X = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ];
> >     Y = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 ];

and when I use this below instruction MATLAB gives me an error :

> > [P,Q] = deconv( X , Y )

error message is :

??? Error using ==> deconv at 21
First coefficient of A must be non-zero.

Why does this message appear ? 
Please help me.
thanks

Comment: I'd say the message appears because the first element of `Y` is zero. Just remove the first element. It's like saying that you have a quadratic `0 x^2 + 2x + 3`, which isn't really a quadratic at all.

Comment: How can I remove first elemant of Y ?

Comment: No idea, I use Matlab extremely rarely. [Look at this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245581). Maybe say `Y(1) = []`, that's what that site suggests. But if this is a general problem, you should write some general solution to prune the leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

In general, try the following to zero-trim `Y` on the left side:

```
ind = find(Y~=0, 1, 'first');
[q,r] = deconv(X, Y(ind:end))
```